# Get the request action parameter value after switchMap action is completed

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a simple effect which calls an API to get data and after I get the data, I dispatch an action to save the data in store. I would like to do another action or operation based on the action request. Is that possible?

```
  loadMoviesById$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
    mergeMap((action) => this.moviesService.getAll(action.id)
      .pipe(
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      )),
     tap((action) => {
            console.log(action.id) //How can I get action.id without passing with loaded success
        })
    )
  );
```

I am looking to pass the action. id to the tap parameter which is a request parameter for the movies

Comment: You could dispatch multiple actions from your effect (although this is a bit of an anti-pattern)..

Comment: You can just put `tap` inside `mergeMap` wherever you want because it's in the same closure.

Comment: @martin Will the tap inside mergeMap run after the service call is completed and map of loading movies is completed? And just to be sure, the tap won't be called if catch error is called

Answer (score 1):

Since it's outside of the scope where the action's id is known, you can't access it.
As a fix, you have two options:

- move the `tap` method inside the `mergeMap` scope
- add the `id` to the `Movies Loaded Success` action

Comment: Will the tap inside mergeMap run after the service call is completed and after the map of loading movies is completed? And just to be sure, the tap won't be called if catch error is called

Comment: Well... you can easily test that ‍♂️ I suppose if you add it between both operators that it will only be called on succes, if you add it after the catchError it will be invoked every time.

Comment: If I add it after catchError, will it always be called when the API call moviesService.getAll is completed?